# variable declaration conflict while redirection to another route using router.push

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am creating a common httpService file from which my all http calls will be called. and in this on a http status 403 i want to redirect to '/profile' route. And after redirection it is showing error

[Vue warn]: The computed property "errors" is already defined in data.

found in

--->  at resources/js/components/Admin/Profile.vue

It looks like it is a conflict of data declaration.

httpservice.js

```
getRequest: function (parameters,callBackFunction) {
    let response = '';
    let url = 'url' in parameters ? parameters["url"] : "";
    let data = 'data' in parameters ? parameters['data'] : "";
    axios
    .get(url,{
        params:data
    }).then(data    =>  {
        if(data.status == 200){
            response = data.data.data;
            callBackFunction(response);
        }
    }).catch(error  =>  {
        if(error.response.status == 403){
            console.log(router);
            router.push({path: '/profile'});
        }
    });
}
```

profile.vue

```
data() {
    return {
    errors: [],
    form: new Form({
    password: "",
    new_password: "",
    confirmed_password: ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not that complicated.

[Computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) depends on the values defined in data properties. And these properties will be extended/assigned into the Vue instance directly (so that you can call `this.errors`).

Therefore, you can't reuse the same property name in both `data` and `computed` object. Because reusing the name means overriding the existing data, which means computed values can't depend on data values anymore.

In your code, you only shows:

```
data() {
    return {
    errors: [],
    form: new Form({
    password: "",
    new_password: "",
    confirmed_password: ""
}
```

According to the error:

> [Vue warn]: The computed property "errors" is already defined in data.

I believe you also wrote something like:

```
computed: {
  ...
  errors: function(){}
  ...
}
```

in Profile.vue too. Just change one of those names will solve your problem.

**EDIT**

To demonstrate the problem:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
      errors: [
        'error 1',
        'error 2'
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    errorString(){
      return `Errors: ${this.errors.join(', ')}.`
    }
  },
  template: `<div id="app">{{errorString}}</div>`
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

The above works fine, while the below will cause an unexpected result and a same Vue warning that you got:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
      errors: [
        'error 1',
        'error 2'
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    errors(){
      return `Errors: ${this.errors.join(', ')}.`
    }
  },
  template: `<div id="app">{{errors}}</div>`
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```